# How can I remap the volume scroll wheel to mouse wheel on a Corsair K70 keyboard?

Tags: windows, keyboard, remapping, mouse-wheel

How can I remap the volume scroll wheel to mouse wheel on a Corsair K70 keyboard? (e.g., instead of increasing the volume, I want the scroll to send a mouse wheel up signal)

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AutoHotkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) to remap any volume up/down signal to wheel up/down:

```
Volume_Up::WheelUp
Volume_Down::WheelDown
```

However, it will remap any volume up/down signal, not just the K70 volume scroll wheel, so this solution isn't perfect.

FYI, solution for Linux: [Re map volume key to scroll up or down in Linux](https://superuser.com/q/1700077/116475)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys/releases), which remaps keyboard keys using the registry. It doesn't require running anything in the background all the time, unlike AutoHotkey, and I don't think it will mess with other volume commands.

Comment: SharpKeys does not support the volume up/down buttons on the corsair keyboard. :(

Answer (score -1):

You can use #ifwinactive? to set a specific software where this function will work. In my case, I was trying to scrub through the video on Adobe Premiere Pro to take screenshots, so I used:

```
#UseHook
#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 999999999
#ifwinactive? ahk_exe adobe premiere pro.exe

Volume_Up::WheelUp
Volume_Down::WheelDown
return
```

Comment: This lacks critical information, like, where you use this code in order to make it do what you claim it does.