# Re map volume key to scroll up or down in Linux

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, bluetooth, scrolling, hid

How can I re-map the volume up / down keys on my bluetooth keyboard to scroll pages up / down by an adjustable amount?

OS: Linux > Ubuntu > Pop_OS! 21.10

(Is there an easy way to take all HID inputs from a wireless keyboard device and map them to another HID?)

Comment: FYI, for Windows: https://superuser.com/q/1333901/116475

Answer (score 3):

1st thing: Find the keycode: `xmodmap -pk`
After that, you can swap the key like this

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 118 = Delete"
xmodmap -e "keycode 119 = Insert"
```

Check if the key is working, If it works, create a file like with the similar content, then make it excutable `chmod +x yourfile.sh`
Get to GNOME's settings, look for an autostart option, drop that file in, then you're good to go :)